# Program freezes when freeing memory

Tags: c

I have a program with a function to free memory of a struct. It usually works fine but sometimes it just freezes.

This is the struct which I am trying to free the memory for:

```
struct Image {
   unsigned int height;
   unsigned int width;
   unsigned int maxvalue;
   unsigned int *imgdata[];
};
```

This is the function which frees the memory( the printfs are only there to check where it is freezing)

```
void    Image_Delete (Image *img)
{
    printf("1");
    free(img->imgdata);
    printf("1");
    free(img);
    printf("1");
}
```

Sometimes this works fine but often the program freezes at `free(img);`. Are there any errors in my `Image_Delete` function?

Here are my malloc lines for img and img->imgdata

```
Image *img= (Image*)malloc(sizeof(Image*));
img->imgdata[height*width]= (unsigned int*)malloc(height*width*sizeof(unsigned int*));
```

Comment: Is this being called from multiple threads?

Comment: Your code looks fine. It would help to see how you malloc img and img->imgdata. Perhaps you are free'ing it more than once?

Comment: I dont think I'm freeing it more than once. I think I realized a problem with it though. imgdata doesn't always have memory allocated to it. Would freeing memory that hasn't been allocated cause this type of freeze? If so, how do I check whether or not memory has been allocated to imgdata?

Comment: Yes, that would cause undefined behavior. One way to keep track of whether memory has been allocated to a pointer is to set the pointer to NULL at the first opportunity, leave it that way until you allocate memory to it, an set it back to NULL when you free that memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first malloc doesn't allocate enough space:

```
Image *img= (Image*)malloc(sizeof(Image*));
```

That allocates enough space for a "pointer to Image" but you are about to use it as an "Image", which is 3 ints and a pointer. So when you start modifying your newly allocate "Image", you'll end up overwriting arbitrary memory. Also, your `free(img->imgdata)` call uses a pointer which is not contained in `img`'s allocated space, and hence might have been modified by some other part of your program; calling `free` on a value which was not returned by `malloc` could result in arbitrary corruption of malloc's internal state, so pretty well anything is possible.

Here's a hint. Best style is to always write your mallocs like this:

```
Image *img = malloc(sizeof *img);
```

Using `*variable` rather than repeating the type is much less error prone, although you still end up repeating the variable name, so it's not perfect. And there's not point casting the void* which malloc returns.

Also, to answer the question you raised in a comment: it's always safe to call `free` on `NULL`, but otherwise you can only call it on a pointer which was returned by `malloc`. So if you're not going to fill in `img->imgdata` right away, you should clear it to 0. In fact, using `calloc` instead of `malloc` would be even better; in the case of small objects like `Image`, the overhead is negligible.